# Python Numpy: Replace duplicate values with mean value

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I have two measurements, position and temperature, which are sampled at a fixed sampling rate. Some positions might occour multiple times in the data. Now I want to plot the temperature over the position and not over the time. Instead of displaying two points at the same position, I want to replace the temperature measurements with the mean value for the given location. How can this be done nicely in python with numpy?

My solution so far looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# x = Position Data
# y = Temperature Data
x = np.random.permutation([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9])
y = (x + np.random.rand(len(x)) * 1 - 0.5).round(2)

# Get correct order
idx = np.argsort(x)
x, y = x[idx], y[idx]
plt.plot(x, y)  # Plot with multiple points at same location

# Calculate means for dupplicates
new_x = []
new_y = []
skip_next = False
for idx in range(len(x)):
    if skip_next:
        skip_next = False
        continue
    if idx < len(x)-1 and x[idx] == x[idx+1]:
        new_x.append(x[idx])
        new_y.append((y[idx] + y[idx+1]) / 2)
        skip_next = True
    else:
        new_x.append(x[idx])
        new_y.append(y[idx])
        skip_next = False

x, y = np.array(new_x), np.array(new_y)
plt.plot(x, y)  # Plots desired output
```

This solution does not take into account that some positions might occoure more than twice in the data. To replace all values, the loop must be run multiple times. I know there must be a better solution to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach using [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
import numpy as np

# x = Position Data
# y = Temperature Data
x = np.random.permutation([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9])
y = (x + np.random.rand(len(x)) * 1 - 0.5).round(2)


# Find unique sorted values for x
x_new = np.unique(x)

# Use bincount to get the accumulated summation for each unique x, and 
# divide each summation by the respective count of each unique value in x
y_new_mean= np.bincount(x, weights=y)/np.bincount(x)
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: x
Out[16]: array([7, 0, 2, 8, 5, 4, 1, 9, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5])

In [17]: y
Out[17]: 
array([ 6.7 ,  0.12,  2.33,  8.19,  5.19,  3.68,  0.62,  9.46,  6.01,
        8.  ,  1.07,  3.07,  5.01])

In [18]: x_new
Out[18]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [19]: y_new_mean
Out[19]: 
array([ 0.12 ,  0.845,  2.33 ,  3.07 ,  3.68 ,  5.1  ,  6.01 ,  6.7  ,
        8.095,  9.46 ])
```

Comment: Looks nice and yields the same exact result is my solution! Lets see if someone else comes up with another good solution, otherwise I go and accept this one.

Comment: @jrast Sure! No hurries. Just curious on this - Are you seeing any speedup with this approach, if you had a chance to benchmark? I am expecting at least some speedup with this.

Comment: I just compared it to the solution given by @Will : I used a dataset with 300000 datapoints in wich each position occures 3 times (so 100000 unique positions.) Your solution: 10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop, Will's solution: 1 loops, best of 3: 2.16 s per loop. I think my original solution would be in the same range as Will's as it also uses loops.

Comment: Looks like someone is getting into `numpy` now :) +1.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks!! Well numpy is getting some interesting problems, so I thought why not :)

Comment: Just one more note to this solution: the behaviour of np.bincount is somewhat unexpected, the input must be positive and the bins are always  started from 0, so there might be some bins wich are 0! Therefore, the final result must be cleand from any nan's which might be in the array, resulting from a division by zero.

Comment: @jrast Ah didn't know that! At least `nan` issue could be resolved with `isnan` or the bins could be checked for `zeros`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, here's one way to do it that is a lot simpler.

Given some dataset that is randomly arranged, but each position is connected with each temperature:

```
data = np.random.permutation([(1, 5.6), (1, 3.4), (1, 4.5), (2, 5.3), (3, 2.2), (3, 6.8)])
>> array([[ 3. ,  2.2],
   [ 3. ,  6.8],
   [ 1. ,  3.4],
   [ 1. ,  5.6],
   [ 2. ,  5.3],
   [ 1. ,  4.5]])
```

We can sort and put each position in a dictionary as its key while keeping track of the temperatures for that position in an array in the dictionary. We use some error handling here, if the key (position) is not yet in our dictionary python will complain with a `KeyError` so we add it.

```
results = {}
for entry in sorted(data, key=lambda t: t[0]):
    try:
        results[entry[0]] = results[entry[0]] + [entry[1]]
    except KeyError:
        results[entry[0]] = [entry[1]]
print(results)
>> {1.0: [3.3999999999999999, 5.5999999999999996, 4.5],
 2.0: [5.2999999999999998],
 3.0: [2.2000000000000002, 6.7999999999999998]}
```

And with a final list comprehension we can flatten this and get the resulting array.

```
np.array([[key, np.mean(results[key])] for key in results.keys()])
>> array([[ 1. ,  4.5],
   [ 2. ,  5.3],
   [ 3. ,  4.5]])
```

This can be put in a function:

```
def flatten_by_position(data):
    results = {}
    for entry in sorted(data, key=lambda t: t[0]):
        try:
            results[entry[0]] = results[entry[0]] + [entry[1]]
        except KeyError:
            results[entry[0]] = [entry[1]]
    return np.array([[key, np.mean(results[key])] for key in results.keys()])
```

Tested with a variety of inputs this solution should be fast enough for datasets under 1000000 entries.